# How to check whether a list contains `NA`?

Tags: r, na

When the right hand side is a vector, `%in%` can be used to check for `NA`s:

```
> NA %in% c(NA, 2)
[1] TRUE
> NA %in% c(1, 2)
[1] FALSE
> 1 %in% c(NA, 2)
[1] FALSE
> 1 %in% c(1, 2)
[1] TRUE
```

When the right hand side is a list, `%in%` behaves differently:

```
> NA %in% list(NA, 2)
[1] FALSE
> NA %in% list(1, 2)
[1] FALSE
> 1 %in% list(NA, 2)
[1] FALSE
> 1 %in% list(1, 2)
[1] TRUE
```

Is this a bug or a feature?  Is this described in the documentation?

Comment: `sapply` works, I agree, but that is surprisingly complicated for such an easy task. `unlist` works here, but does not work if the list cannot be unlisted (e.g. try `NA %in% unlist(list(as.symbol("3"), NA))`. Ok, `list(NA) %in% list(NA, 2)` works, but why? Oh, I see, `list(NA) %in% list("NA", 2)` also works. So that's not 100% helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use `anyNA`

```
anyNA(list(NA, 2))
```

if the `list` have `vector`s of length > 1, then use the `recursive = TRUE`

```
anyNA(list(c(1, 2), c(NA, 1)), recursive = TRUE)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer my second question: Yes, this phenomenon is described in the documentation (of course):

> Factors, raw vectors and lists are converted to character vectors [...]

Thus, `list(NA, 2)` is coerced to `c("NA", "2")`.  Obviously, `NA` is not in `c("NA", "2")`.  Thus, `anyNA` should be used.

My personal take home message: Try to avoid `%in%` when the right hand side consists of lists.